# Getting geojson data of relations by overpass in Python?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I am trying to use [overpass api for python](https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper) to get osm data in the format of `geojson`. I have successfully run this api to get `way` in the format of `geojson`. 
The code is like:

```
api.Get('%s(%d)' % ('way',319141887))
```

But when I try it for `relation` data like:

```
api.Get('%s(%d)' % ('relation',4431641))
```

, it returns no data. (I'm sure that there is a relation with this id because the way `319141887` is one part of this relation.)

```
{"features": [], "type": "FeatureCollection"}
```

and I am wondering how to get them.

Comment: Can you add the actual value of `relation_id` to your question as well?

Comment: I get it. I have modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the overpass library you're trying to use does not support relations.

See https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/issues/48 for details.

Maybe you can try to do some follow up on Github or implement the missing feature on your own.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I should  merge the features of each `way`

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved this issue (adding support for relations) and created a pull request in the Github folder: https://github.com/mvexel/overpass-api-python-wrapper/pull/76

For anyone still having issues with this, this should hopefully help! It saves each relation as a multipolygon.

How it works:
*Relations* in OpenStreetMap are stored as a series of *ways* (e.g. see http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Relation:multipolygon). Each way has a role - either an inner or outer. Because of this, relations can represent multipolygons and other complex shapes (e.g. a donut shape, which is composed of a circular outer and a smaller circular inner).
The geoJson *relation* data that is downloaded by the overpass API comes as a list of dictionaries. The code posted on GitHub loops through the *ways*, determining the starting/finishing points of each polygon (inner/outer) in the relation, and returning a multipolygon object.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  A good answer should include the information about how to use the suggested solution.  Please [edit] your answer to expand with some explanation, not just a link.